Why Drools 9 Decision Table not executing rules as expected in multi threaded spring boot apache camel app deployed as ecs task
We are building drools DTs as separate jar and using them in spring boot camel app. This app is deployed on ecs fargate as docker container.
We are seeing that DT calls are not returning expected output. Below is screen shot showing that flightStatus is not populated.
enter image description here
We have multiple DTs in shared jar. Below is how those are configured and used.
private static KieModule getNewKieModule(String resourceFile)
    {
        ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource(resourceFile, DroolsDtConfig.class.getClassLoader());
        Resource dt = ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(classPathResource.getPath(), DroolsDtConfig.class);
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem().write(dt);
        //kieFileSystem.write(dt);
        KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
        kb.buildAll();
        return kb.getKieModule();
    }

private static KieModule getCnclRtblRtflFlightStatusCodeKieModule()
    {
        if(cnclRtblRtflFlightStatusCodeKieModule == null)
            cnclRtblRtflFlightStatusCodeKieModule=getNewKieModule(CNCL_RTBLRTFL_FLIGHTSTATUSCODERESOURCE);
        
            return cnclRtblRtflFlightStatusCodeKieModule;
    }

public static KieContainer getCnclRtblRtflFlightStatusCodeKieContainer() {
        
        if(cnclRtblRtflFlightStatusCodeS == null)
            cnclRtblRtflFlightStatusCodeS=kieServices.newKieContainer(getCnclRtblRtflFlightStatusCodeKieModule().getReleaseId());`
        
        return cnclRtblRtflFlightStatusCodeS;
    }

This is how we are interacting with KieSession.
public DroolsInput invokeGetCnclRtblRtflFlightStatusCodeDT(DroolsInput droolsInput)
    {
        long startTime= DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("Inside invokeGetCnclRtblRtflFlightStatusCodeDT:: DroolsInput is", v(LOGKEY,droolsInput));
        StatelessKieSession kieSession = DroolsDtConfig.getCnclRtblRtflFlightStatusCodeKieContainer().newStatelessKieSession();
        kieSession.execute(droolsInput);
        //kieSession.fireAllRules();
        //kieSession.dispose();
        long endTime= DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("invokeGetCnclRtblRtflFlightStatusCodeDT:: completed in {} millisec with droolsOutput",v(LOGKEY_TIMETAKEN,endTime-startTime),v(LOGKEY_OUT,droolsInput));
        return droolsInput;
    }

Is there a way DT execution can be debugged in ecs env and or through enabling drools specific logging.
What could be the issue here if any one have experienced this already.
I tried adding more info logging and still see that output is not as expected. Also tried reproducing the issue locally on laptop but no luck.

What could be the issue here if any one have experienced this already.
There could be any possible bug in here. Yes, developers experience this from time to time... To solve 'any possible bug somewhere' one need to narrow down possible issues by for creating unit test for exact scenario with you input data. Once reproduced, you may debug on narrow down it further. Once you have simplest scenario that reproduces your issue you can post it on SO for advise why does it work the way it works or how to fix it...
